# awk command to split filename based on substring

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a directory in that file names are like

```
Abc_def_ijk.txt-1
Abc_def_ijk.txt-2
Abc_def_ijk.txt-3
Abc_def_ijk.txt-4
Abc_def_ijk.txt-5
Abc_def_ijk.txt-6
Abc_def_ijk.txt-7
Abc_def_ijk.txt-8
Abc_def_ijk.txt-9
```

I like to divide into 4 variables as below

```
v1=Abc_def_ijk.txt-1,Abc_def_ijk.txt-5,Abc_def_ijk.txt-9
V2=Abc_def_ijk.txt-2,Abc_def_ijk.txt-6
V3=Abc_def_ijk.txt-3,Abc_def_ijk.txt-7
V4=Abc_def_ijk.txt-4,Abc_def_ijk.txt-8
```

If no of files increase it will goto any of above variables. I'm looking for awk one liners to achieve above.

Comment: Do you really like a space after `Abc_def_ijk.txt-1,`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code(as your efforts), which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: A `bash` one-liner would be `v=();sep=('' ',');i=0; for f in Abc_def_ijk.txt-*; do v[i++%4]+=${sep[i>3]}$f; done`, except that `v` is an `bash` array, whose elements can be accessed as `${v[0]}`, `${v[1]}`, `${v[2]}`, and `${v[3]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Abc_def_ijk.txt-1
Abc_def_ijk.txt-2
Abc_def_ijk.txt-3
Abc_def_ijk.txt-4
Abc_def_ijk.txt-5
Abc_def_ijk.txt-6
Abc_def_ijk.txt-7
Abc_def_ijk.txt-8
Abc_def_ijk.txt-9
```

then

```
awk '{arr[NR%4]=arr[NR%4] "," $0}END{print substr(arr[1],2);print substr(arr[2],2);print substr(arr[3],2);print substr(arr[0],2)}' file.txt
```

output

```
Abc_def_ijk.txt-1,Abc_def_ijk.txt-5,Abc_def_ijk.txt-9
Abc_def_ijk.txt-2,Abc_def_ijk.txt-6
Abc_def_ijk.txt-3,Abc_def_ijk.txt-7
Abc_def_ijk.txt-4,Abc_def_ijk.txt-8
```

Explanation: I store lines in array `arr` and decide where to put given line based on numer of line (`NR`) modulo (`%`) four (`4`). I do concatenate to what is currently stored (empty string if nothing so far) with `,` and content of current line (`$0`), this result in leading `,` which I remove using `substr` function, i.e. starting at 2nd character.
*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*